# Shared preferences instance null error in flutter

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

in initstate of my class ,I'm trying to instantiate Shared preferences but it seems it is failing to do so , as on run , it returns the error that

```
The method 'getString' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: getString("name")
```

where "name" is the one of the key. I can't understand how do i initiate and get proper instance of Shared preferences because it is necessary for me to have it before building the class. And also i don't want to use FutureBuilder for such small thing.

```
class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  SharedPreferences prof;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((SharedPreferences sp) => prof = sp);
    setState(() {});
  }
   ...........

   ............

   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...........
   ................
          MyListItem(
                      icons: Icons.alternate_email,
                      title: "username",
                      subtitle: prof.getString('name'), // This is where it is showing error
                    ),


........

  }
}
```

here it is showing that prof as null
Please suggest any method to solve this error.

Comment: try to add  prof?.getString('name')

Comment: what do you mean by '?'

Comment: prevents you from crashing your app by trying to access a property or a method of an object that might be null:

Comment: or you add boolean to check if the SharedPreferences are loaded then show your build

Comment: even the app donot crash , i still want the instance but everytime it is showing null , how do i solve that

Comment: this you try to add ? like that prof?.getString('name') !

Answer (score 0):

```
     class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
          SharedPreferences prof;
          bool isPreferenceLoaded = false; // to check if the PreferenceLoaded
          @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((SharedPreferences sp){
      prof = sp; isPreferenceLoaded = true;
    });
    setState(() {});
  }
           ...........
        
           ............
        
           Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     //ifLoaded return you widget
    isPreferenceLoaded ?  
            ...........
           ................
                  MyListItem(
                              icons: Icons.alternate_email,
                              title: "username",
                              subtitle: prof.getString('name'), // This is where it is showing error
                            ),
        
        
        ........ 
    : 
    Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
        
          }
    
    }
```

Comment: it's just keep showing circular progress indicator . I've also tried FutureBuilder but the result was same? I just can't understand what is the issue that it even can't access local storage.

Comment: I update the initState , check it, i run it and its work !!

Comment: I already tried that myself but the issue is same , it is consistently showing circular indicator